# When does weak convergence imply strong convergence, can something be said in general?

Tags: functional-analysis, weak-convergence, dual-spaces

We know (and indeed it's trivial to show) that $x_n \to x \implies x_n \rightharpoonup x$. It is a reason for the name "weak-convergence". We have several examples on this site where we have the converse. I just saw a result in our analysis class which wasn't too difficult to prove, namely

Let $X$ be a normed vector space and $x,x_n\in X\ \forall n\in \mathbb{N}$. Similarly let $L,L_n \in X^*$. If $x_n \rightharpoonup x$ and $L_n \to L$, then $L_nx_n\to Lx$ holds.

This got me thinking, does something hold in general here? If $X$ is reflexive, then from this maybe one could do the following with the canonical isometry $\tau$ (here I am quite unsure and I don't really know what I am doing, but bare with me)

$||x-x_n|| = ||\tau^{-1}(\Lambda_x-\Lambda_{x_n})|| \leq ||\tau^{-1}||\ ||\Lambda_x - \Lambda_{x_n}||_{**} = ||\tau^{-1}||\ sup\{|(\Lambda_x - \Lambda_{x_n})L|:\ L\in X^*, ||L||_*\leq1\} = ||\tau^{-1}||\ sup\{|Lx - Lx_n|:\ L\in X^*, ||L||_*\leq1\} \to 0$

where the last argument stems from weak convergence of $x_n$. I wonder if this is correct and if there are other cases where one can deduce strong convergence from the weak in general. Thank you for your time!

EDIT: I will leave the above as is, otherwise the comments below make no sense. I have found a result where it holds and thought it would be appropriate to post it here.

**Theorem:** Let $X$ be a uniformly convex Banach space. If $x_n \rightharpoonup x$ and $||x||\geq \overline{\lim}||x_n||$, that is $x\mapsto ||x||$ is upper semicontinuous, then $x_n$ converges strongly to $x$.

Comment: By the definition of weak convergence, $|Lx_n-Lx| \to 0\ \forall L\in X^*$.

Comment: Ah. Oops, hehe. Is there a way to make it work you think? Or must we enforce uniform convergence for elements in the bidual? That certainly doesn't make it as nice a result.

Comment: Sorry, I have fooled myself too :) My criticism still stands. That $x_n\to x$ weakly in $X$ does not imply that $|Lx_n-Lx|$ tends uniformly to zero over the unit ball of $X^*$, because the norms of $x_n-x$ need not be close to zero.

Comment: Take, for example, the unit-vectors $e_n$ in $l_2$. Clearly $e_n\to 0$ weakly, but it is not true that the supremum of $|\langle x,e_n\rangle|$ tends to zero uniformly over the unit ball of $l_2$. In fact, the supremum of this sequence over the unit ball of $l_2^*=l_2$ is $1$ for every $n$.

Comment: The last argument does **not** stem from weak convergence and it isn't true.  If you like, weak convergence is telling you that $Lx_n \to Lx$ **pointwise** with respect to $L$.  Pointwise and uniform convergence are very different animals.  In fact the distinction between the two is **exactly** the difference between weak and strong convergence, and shows why the former will never imply the latter in general.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers. It has been quite illuminating for me. Are there special classes of sets where it holds (eg uniformly convex sets for instance)?

Comment: I guess when X is reflexive it holds, maybe trivially so, if $\Lambda_{x_n} \to \Lambda_x$ in norm.

Comment: @uniquesolution, why did not your example match in $\ell^1$? I am dealing with a proof that the two kinds of convergence are the same at $\ell^1$ and I am still confused. Maybe: Taking any $(\alpha_n)\subset(\ell^p)^*$, we have $\sum_j \alpha_{n,j}e_{i,j}=\alpha_{n,i}\rightarrow0$. However, it's not true in $(\ell^1)^*=\ell^{\infty}$, for instance to $(1,1,\cdots)$... Is it? Many thanks.

Comment: @Na'omi Heuristically speaking, $\ell^1$ is a "small" space whose dual $\ell^{\infty}$ is a "large" space (e.g. -- it contains an isometric copy of **every** finite dimensional space). Therefore, weak convergence of a sequence in $\ell^1$ is rather restrictive -- so many linear functionals applied to it transform it into a convergent sequence! - it is so restrictive that it implies convergence in norm. Of course, this is just an intutitive way of thinking. The only way to grasp it fully is to understand the proof well, and try to see why it **does not** work in $\ell^2$.

Comment: Many thanks. This is what I am trying, I think I get some thing but maybe I will post an especific topic about that. Thank you.